# regular expression match text in curly braces and print whole curly braces

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, nagios

I have configuration file like:

```
define host{
        host_name xxxxxxxx1748
        use windows-server
        alias Comet
        hostgroups +bu-automotiveprd,screen-automotiveprd2
        address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
}


define host{
        host_name yyyyyyyyy991
        use aix-server
        alias
        hostgroups +bu-automotiveprd,screen-automotiveprd2
        address YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
}
```

I would like to search *host_name*, and if it is matching, output should be like below:

Example - Let's suppose I would like to search `yyyyyyyyy991` host.

Then the output must be like below:

```
define host{
        host_name yyyyyyyyy991
        use aix-server
        alias
        hostgroups +bu-automotiveprd,screen-automotiveprd2
        address YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
}
```

Comment: Please do not revert formatting changes. Without code formatting the question is difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
perl -0777 -ne '/([^\n]*{[^}]*(yyyyyyyyy991)[^}]*})/ && print "$1\n"' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `perl -0777` Run perl and slurp the whole file as one line.
- `-ne` for each line (`n`), execute (`e`) the following.
- `/(pattern)/ && print "$1\n"` match a regex pattern and add it as first matching group (`$1`), then print it.

**The Pattern:**

- `[^\n]*{ ... }` Match anything from the beginning of a line including "{" to the next "}"
- With the `...` being `[^}]*(yyyyyyyyy991)[^}]*`:

  - Match any character that is not `}`
  - must include `yyyyyyyyy991` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your configuration file is called config.dat and it has *standard* format. Meaning you only have one line before yyyyyyyyy991 and five lines after it, then this command will help you to get the output you want:

```
grep -B 1 -A 5 "yyyyyyyyy991" config.dat

define host{
        host_name yyyyyyyyy991
        use aix-server
        alias
        hostgroups +bu-automotiveprd,screen-automotiveprd2
        address YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
}
```

From [`grep` man](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

```
Context control flage:
  -B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context
  -A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
```

Another solution in case the file config.dat is *not standard*, meaning the key word "yyyyyyyyy991" doen't follow the same pattern in every section, then `awk` can do what you want as follows:

```
 awk -v RS='' '/host_name yyyyyyyyy991/' config.dat
```

RS= changes the input record separator from a newline to blank lines. If any field in an record contains /host_name yyyyyyyyy991/ print the record.

[According to posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

If RS is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a  plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a  shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of FS is.

The output paragraphs will not be separated since the output separator remains a single newline. To ensure that there is a blank line between output paragraphs, set the output record separator to two newlines.

Comment: Many thanks, Goro :)

It is working in this scenario but it is not mandatory that "host_name yyyyyyyyy991" line would be 2nd line, line sequence can be changed.

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar. see my edits ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If your `grep` supports it, you can use the `-z` option to make it slurp the entire file:

```
$ grep -ozE 'define[^}]*host_name yyyyyyyyy991.+?}.' file
define host{
        host_name yyyyyyyyy991
        use aix-server
        alias
        hostgroups +bu-automotiveprd,screen-automotiveprd2
        address YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
}
```

The `grep` options used are (from the `man` page of GNU `grep`):

```
  -z, --null-data
          Treat  input  and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a
          zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.  Like the -Z or
          --null  option,  this  option  can  be used with commands like sort -z to
          process arbitrary file names.
  -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching  line,  with  each
          such part on a separate output line.
  -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).
```

The regular expression looks for the word `define`, followed by 0 or more non-`}` characters (`[^}]*`), then `host_name yyyyyyyyy991` and then everything until the first `}` (`.+?`) plus the next character (the final `.`) which will match the newline.

---

Personally, however, I would do this sort of thing using perl's paragraph mode:

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print if /yyyyyyyyy991/' file
define host{
        host_name yyyyyyyyy991
        use aix-server
        alias
        hostgroups +bu-automotiveprd,screen-automotiveprd2
        address YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
}
```

The `-00` tells `perl` to read the input file as paragraphs, so each record is a paragraph (defined by 2 consecutive `\n` characters) instead of a line. Then, the `-ne` means "Read each input record and apply the script given by `-e` to it". The script itself simply prints any records matching the desired pattern.

Comment: not sure `grep` is working!

Comment: `grep --version grep (GNU grep) 2.20
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: @terdon. it is really strange. not working at all on my side? I am using Centos 7

Comment: @Kasper according to [this man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1p/grep/) I found for CentOS 7, the `grep` it ships with doesn't have the `-z` option. That's why I have "if your grep supports it" as the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: grep --help I see `-Z, --null                print 0 byte after FILE name`

Comment: I don't know how to share snapshot of my screen but it is really not working for me. Maybe a bug!

Comment: @Kasper yes, as I said in my previous comment, _your grep doesn't have -z_. And as I said in the very first sentence of this answer, it only works _if your grep supports -z_. Apparently, you are using an old version of grep that doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 'H;/^define host{$/h;/^}/{g;/host_name yyyyyyyyy991\n/p};d' file
```

Step-by-step:

```
H                  # append line to hold space
/^define host{$/h  # start of entry: copy to hold space (overwrites previous content)
/^}/{              # end of entry:
        g                            # retrieve whole entry from hold space
        /host_name yyyyyyyyy991\n/p  # if host matched, display the whole entry
}
d                  # no other output
```